# How to pass a data value to a stimulus controller upon a load event

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs

I have a Stimulus controller

```
# app/javascript/controllers/clubs_controller.js
// handles micropost javascripts
import { Controller } from "stimulus"
import Rails from '@rails/ujs';
export default class extends Controller {

  connect() {
    }

    wait_for_clubs(event) {
      event.preventDefault()
      console.log("in wait_for_clubs", event.target)
      const id = event.target.dataset.value
      console.log("id", id)
      }
    }
}
```

and html code

```
<div data-controller="clubs">
  <span data-action="load@window->clubs#wait_for_clubs" data-value='<%= @user.id %>'>Waiting for Clubs to be prepared</span>
</div>
```

with the idea that when the page is loaded, the controller has the id of the user.  When I reload the page, I see the following error in the console

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
```

which is triggered by the `var id = event.target.dataset.value;` statement.

However if I change the event from `load@window` to `click`, then when I click the span, the code works and retrieves the id.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you are trying to pass data to a Stimulus controller that exists on the DOM when it loads, the Stimulus docs recommend using [the built-in data API](https://stimulusjs.org/handbook/managing-state#reading-initial-state-from-the-dom).

In your case, that would mean adding a `data-clubs-my-value` attribute to the DOM element where you assign the `data-controller` attribute, like so:

```html
<div data-controller="clubs"
     data-clubs-my-value="<%= @user.id %>">
</div>
```

and then you can get this value from your Stimulus controller by calling `this.data.get("myValue")`

As to why `data-action` didn't work...

The Stimulus docs do [allow for Global Events](https://stimulusjs.org/reference/actions#global-events) so this event *is* being triggered. But when this happens, the triggering `event.target` is `window`, not your `<span>`, so when you call `event.target.dataset`, it is looking for the dataset of the `window`, which does not have your value.

If you want an action in your Stimulus controller to fire upon page load, the best way to handle this is generally by using the [`connect()`](https://stimulusjs.org/reference/lifecycle-callbacks#methods) method.

Comment: I noticed that the attribute name needs to in kebab case e.g. data-clubs-my-value and then you can retrieve it in the controller with camel case e.g. this.data.get("myValue")